# Is it possible to make the elements of an array dynamic?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have this set of codes that allows my form retain the value stored in the table field.

```
<?php 
    $playerpositions = Array("Coach", "Assistant Coach", "Goalkeeper", "Defense", "Midfield", "Forward");
?>
<select name="playerposition" id="playerposition" class="input-field-login2" tabindex="1">
   <option value="-1">Select to Change</option>
   <?php
       foreach($playerpositions as $v) {
           $selected = ($row_player['plyPosition']===$v) ? "selected" : "";
           echo "<option value='$v' $selected>$v</option>";
       }
   ?>
</select>
```

My question now is this, Can one have the array 
`$playerpositions = Array("Coach", "Assistant Coach", "Goalkeeper", "Defense", "Midfield", "Forward");`

be dynamic like below

```
$playerpositions = Array(while ($row_playersa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_playersa)) {
    $playersa[] = $row_playersa;
});
```

Is that possible? Cause what i am trying to do is rather than have the array items hard coded in, i want them to be pulled from a table. Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @JohnConde I have but have noting in the drop down.

Comment: Are you using database ?

Comment: @IvanBarayev Yes i am using a mysql database

Answer (score 0):

Hard-coding these types of things is usually the last resort. What if you need to implement this same dropdown somewhere else? Storing and retrieving from a database table makes sense because you can modify the types in one place and refer to them elsewhere without needing to copy, paste, and maintain the same code in many places.

However, you cannot build an array like that. The way you would do it would be to do this:

```
// example code, not real, assume it produces
// array("Coach", "Assistant Coach", "Goalkeeper", "Defense", "Midfield", "Forward");

$someQuery = "SELECT * FROM `player_positions`";
$playerPositions = $db->execute($someQuery);

// other code...

// Iterate through your playerPositions and produce your options.
foreach ($playerPositions as $v) {
    echo "<option value='$v' $selected>$v</option>";
}
```

Comment: `$playerPositions = $db->execute($someQuery);` (which I'm assuming is pseudo code)  would not produce an array that can be iterated by `foreach`

Comment: If the returned value from `$db->execute($someQuery)` is `array("Forward, Goalkeeper")` you could iterate that with a `foreach`.

Comment: Ok, but your solution is pseudo code, it is not providing any real way to achieve what the OP is looking for. `$db->execute` in itself is not PHP... Unless it's part of a framework so between that line and the `foreach...` line where you commented 'other code'... that's the code he needs... lol

Comment: Okay, you are totally correct, I see what you're saying. I felt like we were dealing a lot with abstracts so I didn't flesh out the code as much as I should have, but yeah, I do agree with you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
$playerposition = array();

while ($row_playersa = mysqli_fetch_assoc()) {
    $playerposition [] = $row_playersa['name'];
}

foreach($playerposition as $position){
    $selected = ($player_row[$plyPosition]===$position) ? "selected" : null;
    echo '<option value="'. $position .'" ' . $selected . '>'. $position .'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But this doesn't achieve what i am trying to do. What this gives is the list of all the player positions in the table.

Comment: You know with a normal form textbox, you can set the value to be such like `value="<?php echo $row_playersa['plyPosition']; ?>">` this shows on the form the record pulled from the datatbase. So now how can that be done with a drop down where the array is pulled from the database table and not from the hard coded values and the value you want be the one to show in the drop down as the selected value.